# how does pipe read all information of a page using SAS?

Tags: sas, pipe

I have a folder which has some tables. Once I opened it, it shows table name, date modified, type and size.
I am trying to read all the information including: table name, date modified, type and size using SAS. so I tried pipe first:

```
filename tbl pipe "dir /abc/sales";
 data new;
   infile tbl pad;
   input all $500.;
 run;
```

the result only has the table name, but no date modified, type and size.
so just wonder how to fix it.
An example folder 'sales' below:

```
table name  size   date modified                type
sales1       490k  10/28/2020 9:32:50 am       sas7bdat
sales2        85k  11/12/2020 4:28:23 pm       sas7bdat
sales3       307k  12/17/2020 1:55:09 pm       sas7bdat
```

Comment: Pipe passes the `dir` command to your OS. `dir` is actually an OS command, you need to add the correct options to your command. You can also use `FINFO()` functions which is not OS specific. https://www.lifewire.com/dir-command-4050018

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your path it looks like SAS is running on Unix.  Not sure what the command `dir` does on your flavor of Unix, but `ls -l` should get the file details on any flavor of Unix.

```
data new;
  infile "ls -l /abc/sales/" pipe truncover ;
  input all $500.;
run;
```

Comment: the 'date modified' was messed up,, e.g. '  ... 1/27/2020 12:29:28 PM  ....' was read as '.... Apr 01 15:11 ....', also, looks like it is messed with SIZE, and it was read as '.... 1933180928 Apr 01 15:11 ....'. so just wonder how can we read it correctly, or how to get the date and time split correctly, or how can read the exact same information as it appears. I tried options like PAD missover dsd, but did not work. just wonder if you can help, thanks again!

Comment: The code you posted is making no attempt to convert the string that the ls command generates into separate variables.  Perhaps you can ask this as a new question.

Comment: just posted a new question with similar header, thanks Tom!